# Changing the value of a cell via excel vba if that cell happens to be part of a non contiguous range

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have seven cells "N13", "D17", "H17", "L17", "P17", "T17" and "X17". That are all empty. I have several shapes that will have macro's attached to them. The macro I need help writing should check to see if the currently selected cell is part of that seven cell range. If it is part of the seven cell range then the macro attached to the shape will simply place a number in that cell. So for example: I have selected cell L17, it is active, I click on the square shape and it changes the value of cell L17 to 4. (Number of sides of the shape.) If I have selected cell M17 and click the square shape it doesn't add 4 to the cell, it simply does nothing. The worksheet this is happening on is called "Main".
I had tried a nested set of OR statements but this didn't work and I think I need to do some form of an intersect but I am unsure how to do this.

```
Sub Three_Side()
' Three_Side Macro

    Sheets("Main").Select
    If (ActiveCell.Row = 13 And ActiveCell.Column = 14) Or _
        (ActiveCell.Row = 17 And ActiveCell.Column = 4) Or _
        (ActiveCell.Row = 17 And ActiveCell.Column = 8) Or _
        (ActiveCell.Row = 17 And ActiveCell.Column = 12) Or _
        (ActiveCell.Row = 17 And ActiveCell.Column = 16) Or _
        (ActiveCell.Row = 17 And ActiveCell.Column = 20) Or _
        (ActiveCell.Row = 17 And ActiveCell.Column = 24) Then
        ActiveCell = 3
        Range("AD1") = Range("AD1") + 3
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a code writing service, so please read the following: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Provide code that you have tried and if/when you run into issues/errors post them too.

Comment: Apologies Zack E & BigBen, just now joined literally and a novice in the subject matter and the ettiquette of forums. Didn't expect a writing service honest, just thought my code was too naff to show. Kind regards.

Comment: That series of conditions looks a bit annoyingly redundant indeed, but as far as I can tell it *should* work.

Comment: Side note, if everything is happening on the `Main` sheet, then you don't need to `.Select` that sheet, it's already selected/active

Comment: Thanks Mathieu for the vote of confidence, its always nervous entering a new arena when your're a novice. I was just future proofing with the select I suppose as I will add further sheets as I progress. I'm hobby coding at present until my teeth are cut, so will probably have a worksheet with many pages of coding examples and problems. Kind of trying to build up little scrapbooks of code relevant to me if that makes sense. :-)

Comment: We all started somewhere.  I learned a lot when it comes using VBA in excel from people like BigBen and @MathiewGuindon.  Just keep trying and also trying new things and when you get stuck or it breaks we are here to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect).

```
Dim checkRng as Range
Set checkRng = Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("N13,D17,H17,L17,P17,T17,X17"))

If Not checkRng is Nothing Then
    ActiveCell.Value = 3
    Range("AD1").Value = Range("AD1").Value + 3
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much BigBen, I have been playing with this and understanding the terminology and it works fine and is understood now thank you. I only changed the ActiveCell for selection as the shapes when clicked on select the cells so it felt right to keep talking in terms of selection. Thank you and take care. Its part of a simple shape game for my young daughter by the way, so thank you from her too. :-)

Comment: You're welcome!. The `Selection` isn't necessarily a cell though, so I'd stick to `ActiveCell` personally. Otherwise, glad to help out!